# Unicorns vs ponies

Tags: discussion, meta, fun, april-fools, unicorns

The unicorn tag wiki says that unicorn are way better than ponies.

I think this is heavily opinion based and it is against the rules of the site.

My rank would be:

1. Pegasus, that can fly so is way better than
2. Unicorn, that has a nice horn so it is slightly better than
3. Pony

Of course, the top would be the [winged unicorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_unicorn), but I don't include it in the rank, since as everybody knows, this one don't actually exists.

Please let me know if you agree with me or have another rank you would like to propose.

Comment: NARWHALS MASTER RACE

Comment: Dragon's would beat all of them I'd say

Comment: I agree that's discrimination against the pony's.

Comment: Winged Unicorns do not exist? go tell [her](http://fyre-flye.deviantart.com)

Comment: Kirins takes the cake, surely.

Answer (score 9):

I propose Manatee, not sure where it fit's into the scheme of things though?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I would say lets organise a Pony vs Unicorn deathmatch, the winner takes all glory!

[image]

Comment: _Pony_ is much smaller than the **unicorn**, he will directly be `impaled`.

Answer (score 3):

On top of `Pegasus` is clearly a `Centaur`. It has no wings to fly but it can talk to people, has four legs and two arms.

Comment: Next thing in evolution would be spiders?